# Simple Html Dom parser not working for these web sites

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I used a simple html dom parser and it is not working for some sites.

```
include_once 'simple_html_dom.php';
$html=file_get_html('http://www.lapenderiedechloe.com/');
```

This causes error like this.

> Warning: file_get_contents( http://www.helloitsvalentine.fr/): failed
>   to open stream: Invalid argument in
>   F:\wamp\www\tool\simple_html_dom.php on line 75"

and

> Unable to resolve the server's DNS address.

Here are some sites that do not work.

```
http://www.lapenderiedechloe.com/
http://www.estelleblogmode.com/
```

Anybody who knows a solution?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like somthing is wrong with your local server configuration. I just downloaded simple html dom and it works fine for me so this shouldn't be an issue in here.

You could try to simply call:

```
file_get_contents('http://www.helloitsvalentine.fr/');
```

or

```
file_get_contents('http://www.google.com/');
```

If both works try to get newest simple html dom. If the first one fail and the other one doesn't there is something with your local DNS configuration for this sites, maybe check the hosts file.

If both failes but those pages load in your web browser you should rather look in your server/php settings:

- try to ping those website from console (if it won't work its rather server/DNS config)
- if ping works try to enable allow_url_fopen in your php.ini if its not
- eventually try to install and use cUrl: http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: in my computer both file_get_contents('http://www.helloitsvalentine.fr/'); and file_get_contents('http://www.google.com/'); works well.

Comment: sorry, Please try with this.$html = file_get_html('http://www.lapenderiedechloe.com/');